# options for (Europe/ international) ruby on rails payment gateway 2012?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment-gateway, activemerchant

What are the options I have as ruby on rails coder to easily integrate a payment merchant into my application. A nice API or gem integration so its just "plug and play" without to much hassle and the below options. This would fit most small startups site's I guess. So what do you use or what is advisable?

I know active merchant but its to much hassle to integrate with all kinds of payment solutions from different bankings. I need the best option for *Europe* now it would be nice if its support USA to but if this would add extra costs then then the europa one should favor.

**Criteria:**

- International payment processing preferrable
- Pay by CreditCard, bank account, SMS, calling phone numbers
- Recurred billing, option to have billing extended automatic every month if user grants this

**Country's**

- Europe ( main target for the next year )
- United states/ etc ( would be nice if the gateway implements option for US payments also)

**Pricing plans:**

- only pay for each transaction
- pay low fee( not more than 5 dollar each month ) and have lower pay per transaction

I look for a compare, a excel sheet with all those services would be nice but a lot of time to produce and update so I thought lets ask fellow coders here for some up2date advice! thx

Some I found so far:

- https://stripe.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as international providers go, you do have some good options. Braintree is currently in Beta for Europe and will fully launch to everyone very soon. If you'd like to try it out sooner, then you can request to be part of the beta process here: https://www.braintreepayments.com/tour/international You'll be able to process over 100 currencies from anywhere in the world.

Comment: Yes very nice what you guys have doing, came across the website earlier. The problem is you have to set your own vars to get a price and from my understanding there is no pay on transactions only. This is a big downer for me, As a one man coder with little budget I would like to minimize costs like this as much as possible. I think if you would introduce a pay as you guy you will get a lot more customers, like me, that want to pay but not at a fixed price plan every month.

Comment: Lets stay small for example. 10 transactions pro month each 5 dollar. I get a $110 pricetag. Wich is waaay to much. I think seriously you guys should consider introducing a small package. Ofcourse I hope to have many more transactions but having to pay this with your product there are cheaper solutions out there although I -would- prefer to use braintree it looks like the most solid allround solution I found so far.

Comment: @Rubytastic Our U.S. customers currently pay only 2.90% + $0.30 per transaction.  No monthly fees.  (https://www.braintreepayments.com/pricing)  We hope to bring this simplicity to international customers in the coming months.

Comment: Thanks for taking this option to international customers. There's a wide group of developers outside the usa that could really benefit your strong platform with this flexible pricing. Do you have a rough ETA when this will be finished? Q1,2 2013? thx